# CodeIgniter in Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: codeigniter, ubuntu, virtualhost

I'm trying to move my CI project from my localhost in windows to Ubuntu. I'm working with:

In my cognfig.php

```
$config['base_url'] = '';

$config['index_page'] = 'index.php';
```

My Virtual Host:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>

  # Admin email, Server Name (domain name) and any aliases
  ServerAdmin mymail@mymail.com
  ServerName  mywebiml.com
  ServerAlias www.mywebiml.com


  # Index file and Document Root (where the public files are located)
  DirectoryIndex index.php
  DocumentRoot /var/www/html/CLASE

</VirtualHost>
```

The root folder of the CI application is "CLASE".
Also, I added entries in /etc/hosts

```
MyIp   mywebiml.com
MyIp   www.mywebiml.com
```

The problem being, I keep getting the custom 404 error from CI when I try access my page.

Comment: have you enabled your site using `a2ensite` ?

Comment: Yes. It has to be somethign about the CI conf, because i get the custom 404 error of codeIgniter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First you MUST give `$config['base_url']` a value. Use the following

```
$config['base_url'] = 'http://mywebiml.com/';
```

Second, make sure you are using the file and class naming scheme CI requires. Class files must be named in a Ucfirst-like manner, while any other file name (configurations, views, generic scripts, etc.) should be in all lowercase.

Bad:

```
some_class.php
```

Good:

```
Some_class.php
```

Class names should always start with an uppercase letter. Multiple words should be separated with an underscore, and not CamelCased.

Bad:

```
class someClass {
```

Good:

```
class Some_class {
```

File names and class names must be exactly the same - case-sensitive.

The above rules won't matter on a Windows based development environment but will on a linux system like Ubuntu.

If you are using `.htaccess` to rewrite URLs so the `index.php` is removed use the following.

```
$config['index_page'] = '';
```

Comment: Thank you! Changing lowercase to uppercase in the classes worked!